# Proof of $\sigma(f^{-1}(C)) \subset f^{-1}(\sigma(C))$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $f$ be a mapping such that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $C$ a colection of subsets of Y. Then $\sigma(f^{-1}(C)) \subset f^{-1}(\sigma(C))$.

I know that this result can be proven by first showing that $ f^{-1}(\sigma(C))$ is a sigma algebra that contains $f^{-1}(C)$. Then, by definition of $\sigma(f^{-1}(C))$ (smallest sigma algebra that contains $f^{-1}(C)$), the result is proven.

However, I was trying to make a different proof. The idea is to consider all the sets that belong to $\sigma(f^{-1}(C))$ and show that they also belong to $ f^{-1}(\sigma(C))$.

- $\emptyset \in \sigma(f^{-1}(C))$. Then, $\emptyset \in \sigma(C) \implies \emptyset=f^{-1}(\emptyset) \in  f^{-1}(\sigma(C))$
- $f^{-1}(C) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(C))$. Then, $ C \in \sigma(C) \implies f^{-1}(C) \in  f^{-1}(\sigma(C))$
- $A \in f^{-1}(C) \implies \{A,A^c\} \in \sigma(f^{-1}(C))$. We can write $A=f^{-1}(a)$ for some $a \in \sigma(C)$. Then, $\{a,a^c\} \in \sigma(C) \implies \{f^{-1}(a), f^{-1}(a^c)\}=\{A,A^c\} \in f^{-1}(\sigma(C))$
- $A_i \in f^{-1}(C) \implies \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i \in \sigma(f^{-1}(C))$. We can write $A_i=f^{-1}(a_i)$ for some $a_i \in \sigma(C)$. Then, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}a_i \in \sigma(C) \implies f^{-1}(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}a_i)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} f^{-1}(a_i)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i \in f^{-1}(\sigma(C))$

Is this a complete proof?

Comment: What are $f$ and $C$? Please include full details and context in your question. You should also proofread your proposed proof carefully and make sure you are using the symbol $\in$ appropriately.

Comment: It doesn't look like your proof is complete. For example, you've addressed a set of the form $B=\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ for $A_i\in f^{-1}(C)$. But what about the complement of $B$? This won't be covered by your "complement step" because $B$ is not the complement of a set in $f^{-1}(C)$, it's only the complement of a countable union of such sets. (Of course, it's impossible to say for sure since I don't know what $f$ or $C$ are.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to clear up the reason why the the first proof you suggest is the right way to go, and your second proposed proof isn't enough.

The basic idea is this. Suppose I have a set $Y$ and a collection $\mathscr{C}$ of subsets of $Y$. Your proof suggests that I can describe any set $B$ in $\sigma(\mathscr{C})$ as satisfying one of the following conditions:

1. $B$ is the empty set or $Y$ (see the footnote below).
2. $B$ is in $\mathscr{C}$ or the complement of a set in $\mathscr{C}$.
3. $B$ is the union of countably many sets in $\mathscr{C}$.

But this is not the case. For example, suppose $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathscr{C}$ is the collection of singletons. Then $B=\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0,1\}$ is in $\sigma(\mathscr{C})$, but does not fit any of the three descriptions.

Instead $B$ results from a combination of properties 2 and 3: it is the complement of a union of countably many sets in $\mathscr{C}$. So these are examples of sets that may not be covered in the above list. Note also that adding these to the list won't necessarily do it either (in general). Indeed I could take sets $B_1,B_2,\ldots$ each of which is a complement of union of countably many sets in $\mathscr{C}$. Then $B=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i$ is in $\sigma(\mathscr{C})$, but doesn't necessarily fall under any of the previous descriptions.

---

Footnote: Your second bullet also shows a misunderstanding. $\mathscr{C}$ is a *collection* of subsets of $Y$, not a subset of $Y$. So writing "$\mathscr{C}\in\sigma(\mathscr{C})$" doesn't make sense. What is true is that $\mathscr{C}\subseteq\sigma(\mathscr{C})$. This is precisely why I use $\mathscr{C}$ instead of $C$. It helps me psychologically to remember what kind of object $\mathscr{C}$ is.

In general, you are not using the symbol $\in$ correctly. As another example, you write that $A\in f^{-1}(\mathscr{C})$ implies $\{A,A^c\}\in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathscr{C}))$. But the latter expression says that the $2$-element set $\{A,A^c\}$ is an element of $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathscr{C}))$. This is very different from saying that $A$ and $A^c$ are two elements of $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathscr{C}))$, which is what you meant. So the proper way to write this is $\{A,A^c\}\subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathscr{C}))$.